# Sorting an array of hash references

Tags: perl, sorting

I want to sort an array of hash references using the following snippet:

```
@order = sort { $VAR1->[$a]->{'tom'} <=> $VAR1->[$b]->{'tom'} } @$VAR1};
```

and `$VAR1` structure is as follows:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'tom' => '2.5',
            'color' => 'Johnson',
            'book' => 'ANSA',
            'dog' => 19
          }, ...
```

This is the error I'm getting when it sorts:

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at part2.pl line 47.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at part2.pl line 47.
Use of reference "HASH(0xa91cd8)" as array index at part2.pl line 47.
Use of reference "HASH(0xa91d68)" as array index at part2.pl line 47.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at part2.pl line 47.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at part2.pl line 47.
Use of reference "HASH(0xa91df8)" as array index at part2.pl line 47.
Use of reference "HASH(0xa91e88)" as array index at part2.pl line 47.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at part2.pl line 47.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at part2.pl line 47.
Use of reference "HASH(0xa91f18)" as array index at part2.pl line 47.
Use of reference "HASH(0xa91fa8)" as array index at part2.pl line 47.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at part2.pl line 47.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at part2.pl line 47.
Use of reference "HASH(0xa92038)" as array index at part2.pl line 47.
Use of reference "HASH(0xa920c8)" as array index at part2.pl line 47.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at part2.pl line 47.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at part2.pl line 47.
Use of reference "HASH(0xa92158)" as array index at part2.pl line 47.
Use of reference "HASH(0xb9a2c0)" as array index at part2.pl line 47.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at part2.pl line 47.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at part2.pl line 47.
```

My question is: what is the right syntax to use for sort? Would I have to grep or map anything in order to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can write either

```
my @order = sort { $VAR1->[$a]{tom} <=> $VAR1->[$b]{tom} } 0 .. $#$VAR1;
```

to get a sorted list of indices into `@$VAR`, or

```
my @order = sort { $a->{tom} <=> $b->{tom} } @$VAR1;
```

to get the elements of `@$VAR1` in sorted order.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick!

```
                @order = sort {$a->{'tom'} <=> $b->{'tom'}} @$VAR1;
                foreach (@order) {
                        print "$_->{color}";
                }
```

Comment: Why not explain what was wrong as well?  Your syntax was fine, but the body of the sort would only make sense if you were sorting an array of indexes into @$VAR1, rather than the elements of @$VAR1.

Comment: You don't need to quote the variables you give to [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html "perldoc -f print"). Also for such a simple loop I would write it: `print $_->{color}, "\n" for @order;`